# QueryDict list is not modified

Tags: python, django, dictionary, request, mutable

I can't modify the list of a mutable QueryDict object:

```
copy_GET = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3', mutable=True)
l = copy_GET.getlist('a')
l
[u'1', u'2', u'3']

l.append(u'4') # add a new value to the list
copy_GET.getlist('a') # but list is not modified
[u'1', u'2', u'3']

copy_GET # query dict is not modified
<QueryDict: {u'a': [u'1', u'2', u'3']}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L142) of `getlist`, you can see that it creates a new list each time it is called. Modifying the list won't alter the query dict.

You can use [`setlist`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L142) to set the key to the updated list.

```
copy_GET = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3', mutable=True)
l = copy_GET.getlist('a')
l.append(u'4')
copy_GET.setlist('a', l)
```

Comment: I can see, from django 1.11 getlist is returning  a  new list, for modifying  I think is: 
copy_GET.setlist('a', l)

Comment: Yes, `copy_GET.setlist('a', l)` looks correct, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue, and my solution is:

```
mutable = query_params._mutable  # get out of the initial mutable
query_params._mutable = True
ip_list = query_params.pop('ip')
query_params._mutable = mutable # set the initial mutable
```

Answer (score 0):

we can convert it to a mutable `QueryDict` instance by copying it:

```
request.GET = request.GET.copy()
# update querydict like
request.GET['hi'] = 'hello'
```